# Macro to Copy One Sheet to Multiple Sheets with Dynamic Range

Tags: excel, vba

Fellow VBA Wizards,

Using the following code, I was able to generate multiple sheets with tab names equal to a dynamic range:

```
Sub SheetMacro()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Control_Sheet").Range("F7")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

---

I'm running into a bit of a snag when attempting to copy a source template w/formulas (EAC Summary) into all recently created sheets. Adding this code duplicates the EAC Summary, but it does not name the tabs within the dynamic range:

```
Sub SheetMacro()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Control_Sheet").Range("F7")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet

        Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EAC Summary")
        ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    Next MyCell  

End Sub
```

---

Is there an optimal method to combine the code in such a way to replicate the source template, and name the tabs according to inputs in the dynamic range?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you just trying to copy `EAC Summary` and then rename it?  If so, you should do the rename step after the `Copy` step.  If that's not the goal, please clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you. This code replaces the EAC Summary Tab name with the first cell in the range, but the code errors out because the EAC tab is renamed:

Sub SheetMacro2()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Control_Sheet").Range("F7")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
          
        Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EAC Summary")
        ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet

    Next MyCell

End Sub

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on how to prevent the code from over-riding the original EAC Template tab name?

Answer (score 0):

I was able utilize an alternative command for copying, which resolved my initial question. Here is the code, for anyone that may run into this going forward:

```
Sub SheetMacro3()
Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("Control_Sheet").Range("F7")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
Sheets("EAC Summary").Visible = True   'displays master template
For Each MyCell In MyRange

    Sheets("EAC Summary").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
Next MyCell
Sheets("EAC Summary").Visible = False 'hides master template
End Sub
```